# Set HorizontalGridView to not Scroll in Vertical

Tags: android, scroll, android-gridview

I'm using the [HorizontalGridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/HorizontalGridView.html) to create a slide of products, but I only need that the slide scroll in horizontal. I try `setVerticalScrollBarEnable(false)` but don't work.

I think that the problem isn't the Scroll, because is a movement like as moving all horizontalgridview in all directions.

Part of my code:

```
public class ListProductsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

private HorizontalGridView gridView;
private OffersAdapter offersAdapter;
private ArrayList<Offer> offers;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    offersKey = getArguments().getStringArrayList(Constants.EXTRA_OFFERS_KEYS);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_products_fragment,null);

    gridView = (HorizontalGridView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_gridview);
    gridView.setNumRows(2);
    gridView.setRowHeight(225);

    return view;

}}
```

my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="500dp">

    <android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
        android:id="@+id/product_gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```